# Customize Error: Google OAuth 2 authorization - Error: redirect_uri_mismatch

Tags: javascript, angular, google-oauth

I have integrated Angular 10 App with google oauth Sign-In and I'm getting the error below, which is expected since I haven't setup the redirect url in console. I'm however looking for a way of customizing the error to user friendly maybe display "Unauthorized."
I'm using [Angular Social Login](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angularx-social-login) package.

```
Authorization Error
Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch
The JavaScript origin in the request, https://<appUrl>.com, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client. Visit https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient/${your_client_id}?project=${your_project_number} to update the authorized JavaScript origins.
```

Comment: The error messega says " https://<appUrl>.com," not exist. So, check the initialize Auth0, because you forgot to change https://<appUrl>.com to real enviroment url

Comment: If you want to change the error message, don't you have to `try`, `catch`, and `throw` a custom error?